# Use root URL when using templates

Tags: go

I feel like this a simple problem, but I'm an utter noob and I cant seem to find an answer.

I'm using the following to present a specific html template based on the URL path

```
func handleTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    templates := populateTemplates()
    requestedFile := r.URL.Path[1:]
    t := templates.Lookup(requestedFile + ".html")
    if t != nil {
        err := t.Execute(w, nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    } else {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handleTemplate)
    http.Handle("/img/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))
    http.Handle("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))
    // Dev port binding
    bind := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", "0.0.0.0", "5000")
    fmt.Printf("listening on %s...", bind)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(bind, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

So that works great if I have a template called home.html.. I can browse to localhost/home and it will present me the right template.

However I want the user to browse to localhost/ and be presented with a specific html template. Is that possible without a framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
if r.URL.Path == "/" {
    // Render default/index/whatever page
}
```